# How does the anti-metal uhf rfid tag work?

Tags: rfid

When the RFID tag is close to the metal, because the metal has a strong reflectance to electromagnetic waves, it will be accompanied by a weakening of the signal, the card reading distance will become closer, and serious interference will appear in the phenomenon of card reading failure.
What type of RFID tags should we choose? And what is the features of the anti-metal uhf rfid tag?

Comment: What metal?  What is your use case ?  Asking what type you should choose, makes this opinion based, hence off topic.

Comment: The “anti-metal” tags usually have a sheet of ferrite behind the tag. This prevents the formation of eddy currents in the metal, which in turn causes the interference.